# CComModule::Unlock();

Tags: c++, com

I've been trying to determine what this function does, however I cannot seem to find it anywhere under the MSDN documentation of the CComModule class.

Could anyone tell me what it is used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is for [`DllCanUnloadNow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690368(VS.85).aspx) to work properly.

You know that when you call `CoCreateInstance()` for an in-proc server COM automagically calls `LoadLibraryEx()` to load the COM server DLL if necessary. But how long is the DLL kept loaded? In fact COM calls `DllCanUnloadNow()` for every loaded COM server DLL periodically. If it returns `S_OK` COM is allowed to call `FreeLibrary()`.

When is it safe to unload the DLL? Obviously you can't unload it until all the objects implemented by the DLL are destroyed. So here comes "lock count" - an global integer variable counting the number of live objects implemented by the DLL.

When a new COM object is created - `CComModule::Lock()` is called from its constructor (usually [`CComObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aehcbwe0(VS.80).aspx) constructor) and increments the variable, when an object is destroyed - `CComModule::Unlock()` is called from its destructor and decrements the variable. When `CComModule::GetLockCount()` returns zero it means that there no live objects and it's safe to unload the DLL.

So the lock count is very similar to the reference count implemented by `IUnknown`. The reference count is per object, the lock count is per COM in-proc server.